# PaperClip Error NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError when scaling images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip

I have been banging my head against this for several days. Recently, my image uploader has stopped working properly. I have investigated several possibilities, but have none of the suggested solutions have worked in my case.

The error message is:

```
#<Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError:Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError>
```

Here are the details:

- Mac OS X 10.8.3
- ImageMagick 6.8.4-4 2013-03-29
- libtool => /usr/bin/libtool
- Rails 3.2.13
- Ruby 1.9.3p194

`development.rb` contains appropriate path (and I have verified that it is correct using `which identify`)

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/"
```

`Gemfile.lock` (relevant portion)

```
paperclip (3.4.1)
  activemodel (>= 3.0.0)
  activerecord (>= 3.0.0)
  activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
  cocaine (~> 0.5.0)
```

MODEL (I am updating a classroom object, but the picture resides in the location model. `(Classroom has_one :location, :as => :locatable)`

Model `location.rb`

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  ## Paperclip method for uploading location images

  has_attached_file :picture, :styles => {:show => "1200x500#", :medium => "300x300#", :thumb => "100x100>"}, :convert_options => {:show => "-gravity center"}  
  has_attached_file :building_sign, :styles => { :show => ["1200x500#", :jpg], :medium => ["300x300#", :jpg], :thumb => ["100x100#", :jpg] }, :convert_options => {:show => "-gravity center"}
  belongs_to :locatable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :location_type  
  validates :name,  :presence => true

  validates :latitude, :presence => true,
                       :length => {:within => 9..18},
                       :numericality => true
  validates :longitude, :presence => true,
                        :length => {:within => 9..18},
                        :numericality => true
end
```

Controller `classrooms_controller.rb`

```
def update
  @classroom = Classroom.find_by_facility_code_heprod(params[:id].upcase)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @classroom.update_attributes(params[:classroom])
      format.html { redirect_to(@classroom, :notice => 'Classroom was successfully updated.') }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "edit" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @classroom.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

What I've tried.

- I've made sure that the image name is simple (USB2230.jpg), no colons.
- I've updated the version of ImageMagick to the most recent.
- I've also re-downloaded and reinstalled the CommandLine Tools for 10.8.3 (someone suggested that the issue might be related to an outdated libtool).
- I've rebooted the computer.
- I've tried variations on gem versions including

  ```
  # variation 1
  gem 'paperclip', '~> 2.8.0'
  gem "cocaine", "=0.3.2"

  # variation 2
  gem "paperclip", "~> 3.4.0"
  gem "cocaine", "= 0.4"

  # variation 3 (which is what is reflected in the included Gemfile.lock info above).
  gem "paperclip", "~> 3.4.0"
  ```

If I remove the scaling,

```
:styles => {:show => "1200x500#", :medium => "300x300#", :thumb => "100x100>"},
:convert_options => {:show => "-gravity center"}
```

the upload works, but I kind of need the scaling ;-)

Can anyone see something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved this issue.
brew makes a directory call Cellar, /usr/local/Cellar
Verify if you don`t have two ImageMagick, i had one named ImageMagick-Ruby182, so, if you have it run brew uninstall ImageMagick-Ruby182, and also the normal imagemagick, and reinstall image magic.

Answer (score 22):

We just ran into this issue, and it turned out to be an issue where ghostscript wasn't installed. I took the advise of Scott Cornwell and removed the silencing of errors, and then determined that convert was failing because ghostscript wasn't available.

```
   brew install ghostscript
```

Fixed the issue for us.

Comment: This was exactly the cause of my problem - I was using Paperclip to upload and thumbnail PDFs. Not having Ghostscript installed led to sadness.

Comment: Perfect, this solved my issue! I was trying to simply upload a pdf - not doing thumbnails or any manipulation on it. The error message is a bit misleading unless paperclip tries to create a thumbnail for you from the pdf without an explicit request.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue, although my server is on Linux. Can't tell you exactly how to do it because I don't have a Mac to test, but hopefully this points you in the right direction.

This worked for me with ImageMagick 6.8.5-5, Paperclip 3.4.2, latest version of cocaine, Rails 3.2.13:

I went into geometry_detector_factory.rb in the Paperclip gem and commented out the 2 lines around the identify call: *(this step is not necessary, just explaining what I did to determine the problem)*

```
#silence_stream(STDERR) do 
    Paperclip.run("identify", "-format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' :file", :file => "#{path}[0]")
#end
```

along with the corresponding "end" statement. This allowed me to see the errors on the command line when running the "identify" command.

Basically the error said: "no decode delegate for this image format"

You can probably look up that error and get it figured out, but basically what I did was go to usr/local/bin and run: *(also not necessary, unless you want to see what you have installed)*

```
convert -list configure
```

and look for the DELEGATES line. I had another Linux server where ImageMagick was working and after comparing the two I realized the new one had only 2 delegates installed. I was able to run:

```
yum install ImageMagick-devel
```

and then recompile ImageMagick with make, make install and it worked.

You can also find the delegates manually on the ImageMagick site and install them one by one but that library pretty much covered it for me.

Debugging ImageMagick? Ain't nobody got time for that!

Comment: Thank you! That worked on my client machine. (I ended up using mac ports, which I was loathe to do, but I was spending too much time debugging this.) The instructions I followed were here (http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php#macosx). I also had to change my development environment to point to Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/opt/local/bin/"

Comment: What about Ubuntu? :/ Same problem here, still haven't found a solution

Answer (score 6):

Had the problem on my window dev environment, using paperclip 3.5.2, cocaine 0.5.3, and ImageMagic 6.8.8.

Solution was to add:

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = 'C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.8-Q16'
```

to config/environment/development.rb

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issue, but older PaperClip (3.0.2).

In my case I fixed it with:

```
gem 'cocaine', '0.3.2'
```

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling libtool `brew install libtool` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please update the version of paperclip gem and cocaine gem.
Set PaperClip version: 3.4.1
Set Cocaine version: 0.5.

I faced the same problem and my issue was already there in paperclip gem github issues

Comment: The version is already at 3.4.1 and cocaine is at 0.5.0 (as indicated in the Gemfile.lock listed above).

Answer (score 0):

You already mentioned that you tried upgrading ImageMagick, but I had the same issue and upgrading to `ImageMagick 6.8.0-10 2013-03-03` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue with image_magic that was breaking our paperclip functionality in production, but not in development (weird, I know).
Yet even after removing imagemagick from our gemfile and Gemfile.lock locally (running bundle install and all that stuff) and then deploying back to production on heroku, the error persisted in production! (weird, I know).

What ended up doing the trick was running:

```
$ heroku repo:purge_cache -a myAppName
```

(Taken from: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-repo#purge_cache)

When you deploy your app, Heroku caches some things like your assets and installed gems in order to speed up deployment.
Although this is a great feature, it can have side-effects sometimes, and in this case, it seems that something about the imagemagick gem got "stuck" in production's cache, which is why purging solved the issue for us (since after purging, your app will rebuild itself from scratch on your next deployment)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, and I solved it, when i configure the dynamic linker run-time bindings to create the necessary links and cache to the most recent shared libraries using the [ldconfig command](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ldconfig).

So you need to use the following command:

```
sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib
```

Actually, I advice to re-install imagemagick using steps at [how-to-install-image-magick-and-setup-paperclip](http://robmclarty.com/blog/how-to-install-image-magick-and-setup-paperclip).

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record:

```
brew uninstall libtool
brew install libtool
brew uninstall jpeg
brew install jpeg
brew link --overwrite jpeg
brew unlink freetype && brew link freetype
```