# Spree Commerce app not working on server when you click on checkout, while it works locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, spree

I deployed a standard Spree Commerce app successfully to a server with Capistrano. Everything is working fine, but when you click on "Checkout" after having added products to the shopping card you get the "We're sorry, but something went wrong" error while being redirected to /checkout/address.

Locally it works fine when I run the server in production. Here's the [production.log](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6875553).

Does anyone have an idea what could be the problem?

Comment: I can see there only one error: `[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError`. Quick googling points to that link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12793212/2291093 so maybe try downgrading `cocaine`? Check also that question, maybe that applies to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15744843/paperclip-error-notidentifiedbyimagemagickerror-when-scaling-images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just missing the seed data. After running:

```
RAILS_ENV = production bundle exec rake db:seed
```

on the server everything is working fine!